# Nifi: how to avoid copying file that are partially written

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to use Nifi to get a file from SFTP server. Potentially the file can be big , so my question is how to avoid getting the file while it is being written.  I am planning to use ListSFTP+FetchSFTP but also okay with GetSFTP if it can avoid copying partially written files.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Andy's solid answer you can also be a bit more flexible by using the ListSFTP/FetchSFTP processor pair by doing some metadata based routing.

After ListSFTP each flowfile will have attributes such as 'file.lastModifiedTime' and others.  You can read about them here https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.3.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP/index.html

You can put a RouteOnAttribute process in between the List and Fetch to detect objects that at least based on the reported last modified time are 'too new'.  You could route those to a processor that is just a slow pass through to intentionally wait a bit.  You can then run those back through the first router until they are 'old enough'.  Now, this is admittedly a power user approach but it does give you a lot of flexibility and control.  The approach I'm mentioning here is not fool proof as the source system may not report the last mod time correctly, it may not mean the source file is doing being written, etc..  But it gives you additional options IF you cannot do the definitely correct thing above that Andy talks about.

Comment: Thanks Joe for an amazing answer. The latest link is https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListSFTP/index.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the process which writes the file in, a common pattern to solve this is to initially write the file with a specific naming structure, such as beginning with `.`. After the successful write operation, the file is renamed without the `.` and it is picked up by the processor. Both `GetSFTP` and `ListSFTP` have a processor property called *Ignore Dotted Files* which is set to `true` by default and means those processors will not operate on or return files beginning with the dot character.

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum file age property you can use. The last modification time gets updated as the file is being written. Setting this value to something other than 0 will help fix the problem:

[image]